# API to get Get UK street name from post code

Tags: api, geocoding

I am looking for a simple, reliable and free (gratis) API which will return any corresponding UK street name for a UK postcode (preferably with no registration or key required). I am looking to generate test data, so I just need any of the potentially several street names in the postcode.

I welcome the API returning additional information (lat/long, etc), but that info is not necessary.

This is for demo where I am generating dummy, but somewhat realistic, data. I have a list of UK cities with a Lat/Long for each (city centre? Or main post office?), add small fudge for randomness, get the post form the lat/long, then get a street (any street) that corresponds to the post code. It's for a quick knock up MVP where no one will check to that level of accuracy. They just want to see pins on maps with tooltips.